# Return value in generator function Python 2

Tags: python

I'm wondering how I can write a generator function that also has the option to return a value. In Python 2, you get the following error message if a generator function tries to return a value. `SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator`

Is it possible to write a function where I specify if I want to receive a generator or not?

For example:

```
def f(generator=False):
    if generator:
        yield 3
    else:
        return 3
```

Comment: Why don't you write a wrapper function that calls your generator or standard function?

Comment: This should be two functions.

Comment: No, you can't write one function that can somehow toggle between being a function or a generator. If you feel you have an answer, *write an answer*.

Comment: Why is the checking being done inside the 'function'? Do the check for needing a generator in the surrounding code. If you need a generator call a generator. If you need a function, call the functional version.

Answer (score 4):

Mandatory reading: [Understanding Generators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python)

Key information:

> `yield` anywhere in a function makes it a generator.

Function is marked as generator when code is parsed. Therefore, it's impossible to toggle function behavior (generator / not generator) based on argument passed in runtime.